# C# Custom Action dll - Access Denied

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, custom-action, advanced-installer

This appears to be an environmental issue as it is currently affecting one user (as far as we know).

We use a C# custom action dll which depends on a utility dll in our MSI.  When calling the first custom action using these files the user is getting:

```
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory:
C:\Windows\Installer\MSIBAA4.tmp-\ SFXCA: Binding to CLR version
v4.0.30319 Calling custom action
CustomActions!CustomActions.CustomActions.InitializeInstallationValues
Exception thrown by custom action:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException:
Could not load file or assembly 'InstallerUtils, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.  Access is denied.
    at CustomActions.CustomActions.InitializeInstallationValues(Session session)          
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)   
    at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
CustomAction InitializeProperties returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

Since the MSI can write the file but not read from it, seems to me that some form of security software/policy might be in place; is there a Windows API which might let me determine why:

> Access is denied

Comment: Get your (Preventers of) Information Technology department to un-frack the file permissions on that user's machine and/or account.

Comment: *"Could not load file or assembly 'InstallerUtils [...]' or **one of its dependencies**.  Access is denied."* - So maybe a dependency is missing or inaccessible.

Comment: It's not our IT, it's one of our clients'.  This is only happening for one client; the MSI works in hundreds of other environments.  I'm trying to programmatically determine what might be locking out access to the file so that I can pass that information along to the user.

Comment: Today I noticed that the offending .dll isn't digitally signed (it's only temporarily extracted to the target PC).  I'm thinking this may be the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the customer what antivirus/malware products are installed and have them disable them. Retest to confirm if this was the problem.

If that doesn't work do a google search for "cannot load file or assembly access is denied" and ignore any thread that talks about ASP.NET.  DTF doesn't compile to a temporary internet files directory so that's not relevant.  Something on that machine is interfering with your process loading the assemblies that it needs.

If it's some wierd antivirus thing you could try rebuilding the DLL and see if the signature no longer makes the scanner trigger a false alarm.  You could try code signing it also.

I once worked on a project in the 90s where an IBM partner using their own IBM antivirus had problems with running our installer for one build and the next build it was gone.   They went nuts on us (we were EDS so they naturally hated us)  saying we were contaiminated but we weren't.

Comment: Still waiting to hear back from them on AV/Security software.  Our digital cert isn't due for a refresh for quite some time, so if it doesn't like the signature then not much to be done there.  Also having them ensure that they're on the latest version of Windows Installer.